# How to send organization a list of current Employees?

Tags: civimail, civimember

I want to send a scheduled email to our organizational contacts to have them review the list of employees we have on record for their organization (employees inherit a membership status with our organization).

Ideally, I'd like to have a private link that the organization's contact can click that will display all contacts who have a relationship of "Is Employee Of" their organization. This way, they can verify whether our records accurately reflect their current employee listing.

I'm using Joomla 3.14 and civi 5.21.1

Is there a way to create a link like this from civi email? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it using https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor extension to create list of contacts belonging to logged in user contact.